# Will following ever cause RACE CONDITION when accessing ASP.Net Cache Item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I am using the following code, and to me it seems that a race condition would never happen with code below. Or there is still a chance of race condition?

```
        List<Document> listFromCache = Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>;
        if (listFromCache != null)
        {
           //do something with listFromCache. **IS IT POSSIBLE** that listFromCache is 
                                              //NULL here
        }
        else
        {
             List<Document> list = ABC.DataLayer.GetDocuments();
             Cache.Insert(dataCacheName, list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), 
                          System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
```

**UPDATE:** 
Chris helped me solve this problem, but I just thought, I would share some details that would be be very helpful to others.

To completely avoid any race condition, I had to add a check within the true part, else I could end up with a List with zero count, if someone else clears it in Cache ( not remove the item, but just call Clear method on the List object in Cache) after my if has evaluated to TRUE. So then, I would not have any data within my true part of if in listFromCache object.

**To overcome, this subtle RACE condition** in my original code, I have to double check listFromCache in the true part as in code below, and then repopulate Cache with latest data.

Also, as Chris said, if someone else 'removes' the items from Cache by calling the method Cache.Remove, **then listFromCache would not be affected**, since the Garbage Collector will not remove the actual List object from HEAP memory because a variable called  'listFromCache' is still having a reference to it ( I have explained this in more detail in a comment under Chris's answer post).

```
List<Document> listFromCache = Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>;
    if (listFromCache != null)
    {
      //OVERCOME A SUBTLE RACE CONDITION BY IF BELOW
      if( listFromCache == null || listFromCache.Count == 0)
      {
          List<Document> list = ABC.DataLayer.GetDocuments();
          Cache.Insert(dataCacheName, list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), 
                      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
       }
       //NOW I AM SURE MY listFromCache contains true data
       //do something with listFromCache. **IS IT POSSIBLE** that listFromCache is 
                                          //NULL here
    }
    else
    {
         List<Document> list = ABC.DataLayer.GetDocuments();
         Cache.Insert(dataCacheName, list, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), 
                      System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }
```

Comment: No, it's not possible in your comment that `listFromCache` will become null as it's a local reference at that point. If the cache entry is nullified elsewhere, it doesn't affect your local reference. However, you _could_ possibly get a condition where you retrieved a null value, but while in the process of gathering the documents (`ABC.DataLayer.GetDocuments()`) another process has already done so and inserted the cache entry, at which point you overwrite it. (this may be perfectly acceptable for you, in which case, great!)

Comment: You could try locking around it with a static object, but honestly, I'm not sure if that'll work in an ASP.NET context. I don't remember if `Cache` is shared across all ASP.NET processes (which IIRC, have different static contexts) or only shared within each single web worker. If the latter, the static lock will work fine.

Comment: Chris - Thanks for your detailed explanation. Cache in ASP.Net in thead-safe, so if two users insert into the Cache, it will happen without any errors. But in my code if the list form cache is NOT NULL, and then the cache item is removed by the time I reach inside the true part of if  ( not else part). that is my concern.

Comment: I recognize the `Insert` is probably threadsafe, but I'm talking about the time between you running the `Get` operation, gathering documents, then running the `Insert` -- that is inherently a race condition. If your only concern is the commented area, no, once you retrieve the entry, it cannot become null. (however, another thread can modify/clear the list items, but cannot nullify your object reference altogether)

Comment: Chris - But listFromCache is a reference variable pointing to the Cache item. So it could be that by the time I reach inside the true part of if, listFromCache points to a null object. Right? listFromCache is simply a pointer to a Cache Item.

Comment: No, not quite. Once you retrieve the item, it gives you the reference to the object, not the cache entry. If another thread removes the cache entry, the cache itself is pointing now to a reference and does not affect the original `List` you pulled out of it. EDIT: It's like: `var a = new Object(); var b = a; a = null;` In this case, `b` is still pointing to the original `Object` even though `a` is now pointing to null.

Comment: Chris - Thanks. I am very clear now. Appreciate your excellent help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible in your comment that `listFromCache` will become null as it's a local reference at that point. If the cache entry is nullified elsewhere, it doesn't affect your local reference. However, you could possibly get a condition where you retrieved a null value, but while in the process of gathering the documents (`ABC.DataLayer.GetDocuments()`) another process has already done so and inserted the cache entry, at which point you overwrite it. (this may be perfectly acceptable for you, in which case, great!)

You could try locking around it with a static object, but honestly, I'm not sure if that'll work in an ASP.NET context. I don't remember if Cache is shared across all ASP.NET processes (which IIRC, have different static contexts) or only shared within each single web worker. If the latter, the static lock will work fine.

Just to demonstrate too:

```
List<Document> listFromCache = Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>;
if (listFromCache != null)
{
    Cache.Remove(dataCacheName);
    //listFromCache will NOT be null here.
    if (listFromCache != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not null!"); //this will run because it's not null
    }
}
```

Comment: Chris - Appreciate. I am about to try your snippet. Thanks.

Comment: @Sunil I made a pretty significant typo, but I guess you'll find it easily enough. (I had `listFromCache.Remove(dataCacheName)` instead of `Cache.Remove(dataCacheName)`)

Comment: Chris - Just tried your snippet, and it works without issues. So it seems listFromCache points to its own copy of list object and NOT to Item in Cache. Right?

Comment: Chris- BUT. If instead of removing the Cache Item, I simply execute (Cache[dataCacheName] as List<Document>).Clear ( ), after the if has evaluated to true but before I execute something in True part, then yes the listFromCache contains a 0 count. So this is a RACE condition.

Comment: Chris - I guess there is a very SUBTLE race condition in true part of if as per my last comment.

Comment: @Sunil `listFromCache` doesn't point to its own "copy" of the list object, it points to THE existing instance of the list object. So yes, as I stated in one of my comments above _"If your only concern is the commented area, no, once you retrieve the entry, it cannot become null. (however, another thread can modify/clear the list items, but cannot nullify your object reference altogether)"_ This is the same as any code which has more than one reference to the same mutable object. If you plan on **modifying** the list, then you should introduce threadsafe measures to do so.

Comment: Chris - I got you. Sorry I was not remembering the basics of Garbage Collector in C#. That actual object ( in this case List<document>) resides on the heap, and GC will not reclaim it till all references to it are removed. So just removing the reference to this heap location from Cache, will not remove all references. Once the local reference, listFromCache, is out-of-scope then the heap location has no references and GC can then remove it from heap.